# Can't write to file in C:\ even though I set write permissions

Tags: windows, permissions, elevation

Windows 7, SP 1.  I have a file in C:\ that I want to write to (I know, I shouldn't, but let's ignore that).  I know that as a user and even as admin without elevation I cannot.  So I added write permission for the group Users as well, but that doesn't help.  Even adding my user with "full control" permission doesn't help.  Yet, the "effective permissions" dialog shows write access for my user.

How can I set file permissions so that I can write to the file?  What am I missing?

Edit: in case this question doesn't look programmer-centric enough: as a programmer, I'd really like to understand why the file doesn't open and how file permissions really work when it comes to elevation.

Edit 2: Anybody should be able to try for himself: just open an admin prompt, create a text file in C:\, then try to access it from regular explorer without elevation.

Comment: You cannot have elevated access without elevation, and without elevation permissions that would require elevated access are ignored. The only options are radical icacls/setintegritylevel on C:\ or disabling UAC.  Simply put, don't write to C:\

Comment: See [Mandatory Integrity Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb648648), and for a more in depth explanation read the [Windows Vista Integrity Mechanism Technical Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625964). Note that the system drive has a high integrity label that gets inherited by files in the root directory. You can use [icacls](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525) to set the DACL and integrity level on just a file in the root directory without modifying the directory itself.

Comment: @eryksun: That was it! Thanks! This answer is really hard to find on the net if you don't know what to look for. Please make an answer from it, so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

As [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) wrote in the comments, this solves and explains the problem:

> See [Mandatory Integrity
>   Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb648648), and for a
>   more in depth explanation read the [Windows Vista Integrity Mechanism
>   Technical
>   Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625964). Note
>   that the system drive has a high integrity label that gets inherited
>   by files in the root directory. You can use
>   [icacls](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525) to set
>   the DACL and integrity level on just a file in the root directory
>   without modifying the directory itself.

In practice, that means `icacls C:\somefile.txt /setintegritylevel M` does the trick.